# linux -> how to sort in sequence

Tags: shell, sort

how can i get the output below in sort sequence order of 1,2,3,10,12 instead of 1,10,12,2,3 ?

```
avi@tech> get  hardwareNumber=    productNumber

hardwareNumber=1                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=10                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=12                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=2                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=3                               productNumber 526845
```

Comment: Could you provide details on the shell and operating system you are using so that we can better assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output to

```
sort -t= -nk2,2
```

- `-t` indicates the separator
- `-n` sorts numerically, i.e. what you want
- `-k2,2` tells sort to use the second column (and only the second column) to sort the lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need `sort` with the `-n` flag, from `man sort`:

> ```
> -n, --numeric-sort
>            compare according to string numerical value
> ```

```bsh
$ sort -nt'=' -k2 file
hardwareNumber=1                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=2                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=3                               productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=10                              productNumber 526845
hardwareNumber=12                              productNumber 526845
```